# Allow rule to update meteor mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor

The browser console says:

> update failed: Access denied

The code below should allow the client to set the value of `value` array to `undefined` but it fails with the above error.
Any idea why and how to fix it? Thanks

```
//client
const doc = myCol.findOne({element: 'abc'});
myCol.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set: {value: undefined}});

//server
myCol.allow({
   update: function(userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
      console.log(modifier);  //  -----=>  { '$set': {} }  --------------why?
      let edits = {$set: {value: undefined}};

      const userVarified = (userId && doc.userId == userId);
      const ABC = (doc.element === 'abc');
      const XYZ = (doc.action === 'xyz' && doc.element === 'x' && doc.name === 'y' && _.difference(fields, ['values]).length === 0);
      try {
         if (userVarified) {
            if (ABC) {
               check(modifier, Match.OneOf(edits));
             } else if (XYZ) {
               return true;
             }
         }
      } catch (e) {
         return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
 });
```

**edit 1**
The modifier is `{ '$set': {} }`  when the server gets it. Any idea why?

**edit 2**
As per Mikkel answer, which fixed the error in "edit 1".
The code now uses the modifier `{ '$set': { value: '' } }`.

Now the expression `check(modifier, Match.OneOf(checkEdit));` gives false but I expected it to match since what the client sends and `console.log(modifier)` are the same.
Any idea why it is false?

**fixed**
`import { Match } from 'meteor/check'` added to the top of the file and
Used `Match.test(modifier, checkEdit);` instead.

Comment: You almost got it, but you need to use $unset, not $set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to set a value to 'undefined' is non-sensical, and Mongo isn't letting you do it.

I think you should use $unset instead, as per the mongo docs:

> **$unset** The $unset operator deletes a particular field. Consider the following syntax:
>
> { $unset: { : "", ... } } The specified value in the $unset
>   expression (i.e. "") does not impact the operation.
>
> To specify a  in an embedded document or in an array, use dot
>   notation.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/